# Offset with LineTo() not working

Tags: c++, winapi

For a school lesson, I made a simple paint program to draw shapes of different colors. One the exercises wants me to add a cube function to draw with. The exercise want me to draw it using 12 lines using the `MoveToEx()` and `LineTo()` functions (which were covered in the primary lesson).

I know how to draw the cube by using offsetting lines to make the shape, but `LineTo()` doesn't seem to want me to use multiplication or division to find coordinates.

The code for one line goes like this:

```
int lengthX = pt0.x - pt1.x; // 'pt0' and 'pt1' are POINT structs for
int lengthY = pt0.y - pt1.y; // the start and end points of the line.
                             // 'pt0' is the point the use presses the
                             // mouse button, and 'pt1' is where the mouse
                             // currently is or the point where the user
                             // lifts up the mouse button.

MoveToEx(hdc, pt0.x, pt0.y, 0);
LineTo(hdc, pt1.x + (lengthX * (1/3)), pt1.y + (lengthy * (1/3)));
```

The goal of this code is to simple have the line drawn only 2/3 the way to the end point. The problem as far as I currently understand it is when I add `(length_ * (1/3))` to the parameter, it seems to just be ignored altogether.

Why is this, and what could I do to fix it.

(Please try to give an answer still using `MoveToEx` and `LineTo()`. I understand there may be better ways, but this is for school, so I want to try and stick with the parameters given to me.)

Comment: Learn how floating point operations using integer values work.

Comment: Make it `lengthX/3` and `lengthY/3`. `(1/3) == 0`

Comment: When a complex operation fails, break it into smaller operations so you can see which piece is not working. `int x = pt1.x + (lengthX * (1/3)); int y = pt1.y + (lengthy * (1/3)); LineTo(hdc, x, y);`